# Regex working in mongodb commandline but not with mongoose

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema named `Skills` which has a single string field called `name`. I want to perform a search on the field based on a given string.
For normal strings like `java`, its working fine. But, for `C++`, its omitting the ++ part as `+` is a special character in regex. So I replaced `+` with `\\+` which is working fine in mongodb.
To do this, following is my query in mongodb commandline which is giving me the required result:

`db.skills.find({"name": {'$regex': '^c\\+\\+', '$options': 'i'}})`

Following is my code with mongoose:

```
    word = '^' + req.query.word;
    word = word.replace(/\+/g, '\\+')
    word = word.replace(/\./g, '\\+')
    Skill.find({"name": {'$regex': word, '$options': 'i'}}).limit(10).exec(function (err, results) {
        res.json({'results': results})
    })
```

Here I have added the two replace statements to replace `+` with `\\+` and `.` with `\\.`

But, the above code is not working. It's giving me zero result. 
Please help me if I am wrong somewhere.

Thanks,

Comment: try to put `word.replace(/\./g, '\\\\+')` instead

Comment: [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) - no need to escape strings when you use that.

Comment: You should be able to do `/[.+]/g, '\\+'`...

Comment: @Ashish didn't work :(

Comment: @l'L'l didn't work for me

Comment: @NeilLunn I couldn't understand. Without using escape strings, the regex didn't work when I passed `c++` to word.

Comment: @Ashish I did that only for both `+` and `.`. But, didn't work

Comment: What if you do `word = word.replace(/[.+]/g, '[$&]')`

Comment: My original code worked. Actually the bug was with different part of code. In the request only, it was coming as `c  ` insead of `c++` because the browser was omitting the `+`. Fixed that issue. Thanks for your response. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let word = "c++";

Skill.find({ "name": RegExp("^" + word.replace(/\+/g,"\\+"),"i") })
```

or

```
Skill.find({ "name": { "$regex": "^" + word.replace(/\+/g,"\\+"), "$options": "i" } })
```

Both return the document without problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The code was fine. issue was with the request parameter where it was coming as `c  ` instead of `c++`. Browser was the culprit.